# Using SQL to get the Last Reply on a Post

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replicate a forum function by getting the last reply of a post.

For clarity, see [PHPBB](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewforum.php?f=46): there are four columns, and the last column is what I like to replicate.

I have my tables created as such:

- discussion_id (primary key)
- user_id
- parent_id
- comment
- status
- pubdate

I was thinking of creating a Link Table that would update for each time the post is replied to.

The link table would be as follow:

- discussion_id (primary key)
- last_user_id
- last_user_update

However, I am hoping that theres a advance query to achieve this method. That is, grabbing each Parent Discussion, and finding the last reply in each of those Parent Discussions.

Am I right that there is such a query?

---

Here is a update.
I am still having a little trouble but I feel like I am almost there.

My current query:

```
SELECT 
`discussion_id`, 
`parent_id`,
`user_id` as `last_user_id`, 
`user_name` as `last_user_name` 
FROM `table1`, `table2`
WHERE `table1`.`id` = `table2`.`user_id`
```

Results:

```
discussion_id---------parent_id-----last_user_id-------last_user_name
30---------------------NULL-------------3--------------raiku
31---------------------30---------------2--------------antu
32---------------------30---------------1--------------admin
33---------------------NULL-------------3--------------raiku
```

Adding this:

```
GROUP BY `parent_id`
```

Turns it into:

```
discussion_id---------parent_id-----last_user_id-------last_user_name
32---------------------30---------------1--------------admin
33---------------------NULL-------------3--------------raiku
```

But I want it to turn it into:

```
discussion_id---------parent_id-----last_user_id-------last_user_name
30---------------------NULL-------------3--------------raiku
32---------------------30---------------1--------------admin
33---------------------NULL-------------3--------------raiku
```

Id 30, and ID 33 share the same parent_id: NULL but they are the "starting thread" or the "parent post"

They should not be combined, how would I go on by "Grouping" but "ignoring" null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will take the highest (thus assuming latest) discussion per parent_id. Not the neatest solution however ...

```
select discussion_id, user_id, pubdate
from tablename
where discussion_id in
(
  select max(discussion_id)
  from tablename
  group by parent_id
)
```

Comment: When grouping the Parent_Id, it also group those that are Null. The one that are null are not suppose to be group because they are the parent_id themselves. How can I group by the parent_id but ignore the nulls?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT parent.discussion_id, 
child.discussion_id as last_discussion_id,
child.user_id as last_user_id,
child.pubdate as last_user_update
FROM Discussion parent
INNER JOIN Discussion child ON ( child.parent_id = parent.discussion_id )
LEFT OUTER JOIN Discussion c ON ( c.parent_id = parent.discussion_id AND c.discussion_id > child.discussion_id)
WHERE c.discussion_id IS NULL
```

The left join to Discussion c will not match when you have the post with the highest id, which should be the row that you want.

Answer (score -2):

You want [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html). This should work out OK:

```
SELECT MAX(`pubdate`), `discussion_id`, `user_id` FROM `table` GROUP BY `parent_id`
```

You'll obviously need to fill in an appropriate the WHERE clause and LIMIT as needed.

Comment: This would result in an error, stating that 'discussion_id' and 'user_id' must included in either an aggregate or the group by.

Comment: @Fabian, no it doesn't..? If the `GROUP BY` clause weren't there, then it would.

Comment: @jasonbar Fabian's correct! You would need to either put `discussion_id`, `user_id`in the GROUP BY or aggregate them.

Comment: I think mysql (unlike other databases) does let you run that query. but i think there are multiple possible values you could get for the non-aggregated columns, so the results are not necessarily correct

Comment: @Martin Smith, Did you actually try to run a similar query? It works just fine.

Comment: No, Sorry I actually wasn't aware that MySQL was different in that respect. I still can't see anywhere that it is documented that given multiple discussion_ids for a parent_id that it will choose the "right" one though (e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html implies it can be completely arbitrary)